# How do you lose -5 rep?

Tags: support, specific-question

Not that this really matters to me, but the reason isn't obvious, so I'm curious.

In the "Achievements" tool in the page header it shows -5 for yesterday on a 10 month old answer.

Viewing my profile in various forms, I can't find -5 listed.

I've seen -1, -2 and -15 before, and understand how those values could come from, but how do you get -5?  [This page](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) of the help center, doesn't give me clues either.

The answer I'm referring to is [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1028682/excell-which-values-to-increment-and-which-to-not-in-autofill/1028687#1028687).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the ["time" view of your reputation tab](https://superuser.com/users/345678/tyson?tab=reputation&sort=time), I see that this happened yesterday:

[image: +10 -15]

The question owner removed the accept mark on your answer (removing 15 reputation points from you), but a few minutes later the answer happened to collect an upvote (giving you 10 points). That's a net change of -5.

Comment: Ahhh, I see how to find that in the profile now. I clicked about everywhere in my profile except missed the word "time" on the top right of that table, (although I had been to that table, just not with the "Time" option).

Comment: You don't need to click on the “time” option;  just click on the right-pointing triangles to turn them into down-pointing triangles and expand the data that had been summarized (i.e., hidden).